# Change dropdown value after Google Maps Api marker click

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

i hope all of you are having a great day.
I come here with a question i have a form, with a dropdown menu with the list of locations of the company.
And below is my google maps api working. I get all the data from a previously received json from my api.
Im currently trying to make that when click on the map marker changes the value in the dropdown AGENCIA.
Heres the example of the form.

[image: Form]

And here is the code, im almost there but i dont get it to work... right now i make an alert when i click on the marker to see if it the value is correct but when i click it the dropdown menu gets empty.

```
<?php
//Habilitar las sesiones
$codigoError ="";
session_start();

//Validar si existen las sesiones
if(!isset($_SESSION['vsJsonAgencias']))
{
    header("location:../index.php");
}

//if(!empty($_SESSION['codigoError'])){
$codigoError = $_SESSION['codigoError']; 
//}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="SGLabz">

    <title>CitasWeb</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="../vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="../css/portfolio-item.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/form-basic.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script src="../js/form.js"></script>
    <link href="../css/pikaday.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- date new-->
<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body >

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><?php echo '<img alt="LOGO" height="40" width="40" src="http://'.$_SESSION['vsApache'].'/citasweb/icon.png"" >';?>CitasWeb</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <!-- Page Content -->
    <div class="container">


      <!-- Portfolio Item Row -->
        <form class="form-basic" id="form-basic" <?php echo 'action="http://'.$_SESSION['vsApache'].'/citasweb/gestAgenciafunc.php"';?> method="post">

            <div class="form-title-row">
                <h1>Seleccionar</h1>
            </div>

            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Gestión</span>
                    <?php

                    echo '<select name="codgestion">';
                    $jsonData =$_SESSION['vsJsonAgencias']; 
                    $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);

                    foreach($jsonDataObject->TipoGestion as $option){
                        echo '<option value=' . $option->ID . '>' . $option->Nombre . '</option>';

                    }

                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Fecha</span>
                    <input input type="text" id="datepicker" name="fecha" required/>
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-row">
                <label>
                    <span>Agencia</span>
                    <?php

                    echo '<select id="agencia" name="agencia">';
                    //$jsonData = $_SESSION['vsJsonAgencias']; 
                    $jsonData = file_get_contents('https://api.myjson.com/bins/t222l'); 
                    $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);

                    foreach($jsonDataObject->Agencias as $option){
                        echo '<option value=' . $option->ID . '>' . $option->Nombre . '</option>';
                        //CAPTURAR NOMBRE DE LA AGENCIA
                        $_SESSION['vsNomagencia'] = $option->Nombre;
                    }

                    echo '</select>';
                    ?>
                </label>
            </div>

    <body onload = "loadMap()">
    <h2>Agencias</h2>
    <?php
                    //$jsonData = file_get_contents('https://api.myjson.com/bins/t222l'); 
                    $jsonDataObject = json_decode($jsonData);
      ?>
      <center>
    <div id = "map" style = "width:480px; height:480px;"></div> 
      <script>
        // fake JSON call
        function getJSONMarkers() {
          var markers =  <?php echo $jsonData ?>;
          return markers;
        }

        function loadMap() {
          // Initialize Google Maps
          const mapOptions = {
            center:new google.maps.LatLng(13.706360,-89.212204),
            zoom: 10
          }
          infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

        // Try HTML5 geolocation.
        if (navigator.geolocation) {
          navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
            var pos = {
              lat: position.coords.latitude,
              lng: position.coords.longitude
            };

            infoWindow.setPosition(pos);
            infoWindow.setContent('Usted esta aquí.');
            infoWindow.open(map);
            map.setCenter(pos);
          }, function() {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
          });
        } else {
          // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
          handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        }

          const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

          // Load JSON Data
          const data = getJSONMarkers();

          // Initialize Google Markers
          for(agencia of data.Agencias) {
              let marker = new google.maps.Marker({
              id: agencia.ID,
              map: map,
              position: new google.maps.LatLng(agencia.Latitud, agencia.Longitud),
              content: agencia.Nombre,

              })

marker.info = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: agencia.Nombre
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  marker.info.open(map, marker);
  marker = this; 
  alert('ID is :'+ this.id);
  $(document).ready(function(){
  $("#agencia").val(this.id);
});
});
          }
        }
      </script>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=AIzaSyD-h6xw5-2X2DdSmL93dQmrR7p63Q_uv5w"></script>
  </body></center>


            <div class="form-row">
                <button type="submit" >Consultar Horarios</button>

            </div>
            <center>
           <?php
                //print_r($_SESSION['codigoError']);
                print_r( $codigoError);
            ?>
            <br>
            </center><br/>
            <?php echo '<a href="http://'.$_SESSION['vsApache'].'/citasweb/php/menu.php"><img alt="SALIR" height="42" src="http://'.$_SESSION['vsApache'].'/citasweb/php/regresar.png"" width="142"></a>';?>
        </form>

      </div>
      <!-- /.row -->



    </div>
    <!-- /.container -->

    <!-- Footer -->
    <footer class="py-5 bg-dark">
      <div class="container">
            <?php echo '<center><img alt="SALIR" height="50" width="170" src="http://'.$_SESSION['vsApache'].'/citasweb/conticsa.png"" ></center><br/>';?>
        <p class="m-0 text-center text-white">Copyright &copy; Citas Web 2017</p>

      </div>
      <!-- /.container -->
    </footer>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
    <script src="vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/popper/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/pikaday.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/moment.js"></script>
 <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
     $.datepicker.regional['es'] = {
    closeText: "Cerrar",
    prevText: "&#x3C;Ant",
    nextText: "Sig&#x3E;",
    currentText: "Hoy",
    monthNames: [ "Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio",
    "Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre" ],
    monthNamesShort: [ "ene","feb","mar","abr","may","jun",
    "jul","ago","sep","oct","nov","dic" ],
    dayNames: [ "domingo","lunes","martes","miércoles","jueves","viernes","sábado" ],
    dayNamesShort: [ "dom","lun","mar","mié","jue","vie","sáb" ],
    dayNamesMin: [ "D","L","M","M","J","V","S" ],
    weekHeader: "Sm",
    dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
    firstDay: 1,
    isRTL: false,
    showMonthAfterYear: false,
    yearSuffix: "" };
 $.datepicker.setDefaults($.datepicker.regional['es']);
  } );
  </script>


    </body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Could you provide a sample json data?

Comment: Im going to edit the post using a json in the web api myjson right now

Comment: it should be working with the json api from this link > https://api.myjson.com/bins/t222l

Comment: OK - I am working on it now

Comment: Thanks for your time my friend

Comment: Does this line work? `alert('ID is :'+ this.id);`

Comment: Yes Duncan, it shows a popup alert with the id of clicked map marker. for example ID is : 1, ID is: 2, whatever it is

Comment: You have two `<body>` tags in your page, which can't be good.

Comment: I didnt notice that thanks, i was making test adding the google maps api using a previous functional form so i just copy paste the map query with his body tag

Comment: After fixing the HTML, if it's still not working, you might want to try `$('#agencia option[value="' + this.id + '"]').prop("selected", true);`

Comment: Thank you all for your valuable time. Dev8080 show me the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem's with the $(document).ready - it is not required:

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
         marker.info.open(map, marker);
         marker = this; 
         alert('ID is :'+ this.id);
         //----$(document).ready(function(){
         $("#agencia").val(this.id);
         //----});
     });
```

Comment: Marked this as the accepted answer, thank you for your valuable time. Im starting to work with js that worked great.